# how to put some image in table header for iphone

Tags: iphone

i want to insert come png or some black color in table header

```
 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        //tableView.section.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];






        NSString *sectionName = nil;

        switch(section)
        {
            case 0:
                //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bowl.png"];

                sectionName = [NSString stringWithString:@"."];// some black bar
                break;
}
```

}

but i cant put anything :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `UITableViewDelegate` methods instead `UITableViewDataSource`:

```
tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
tableView:heightForHeaderInSection
```

The returned object for `viewForHeader...` method can be UILabel or UIImageView.